# ViewModel and Data Binding

Tags: android

Android has recently introduced [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) and in particular a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html), which is

> designed to store and manage UI-related data so that the data survives configuration changes such as screen rotations

In example provided by Google, ViewModel is used like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        model.getUsers().observe(this, users -> {
            // update UI
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Question:** How does ViewModel suppose to correlate with the [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#custom_setters)?

I mean, in case of data binding there is going to be a `binding` which provides data for the UI.

Is it going to look like this:

```
...
model.getUsers().observe(this, users -> {
  // update binding, that will auto-update the UI?
});
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a variable of your viewmodel type in your layout xml file.
In your viewmodel class implement public methods through which data will be bind to ui.

Then you only need to set view model into binding in onCreate. When you set view model instance in databinding, the data which is already loaded in viewmodel will be set to recreated layout.

In case there is a recycler view in your layout you can implement some public method like initRecyclerView() in your view model class and call it in onCreate() after setting view model in binding or adapter can be set from view model through databinding as well.

Comment: when i again set data using setValue() method(lets say after a network call), the data isnt reflected in ui. Do i have to attach an observe like above?

Comment: If your ViewModel extends BaseObservable from android.databinding you can call notifyChange() to update all fields or notifyPropertyChanged(BR.yourProperty) to update the only field bound to the property. To use the second one your public property or its getter should be annotated with @Bindable annotation. You can also use ObservableField. For more details you can checkout this https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-observability-9de4ff3fe038

Comment: Thanks a lot i just needed to extend my viewmodel to Observable.

Answer (score -1):

Your layout_name.xml file would look like

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

   <data>
       <import type="android.view.View"/>
       <variable
           name="model"
           type="com.yourpackage.ViewModelName"/>
   </data>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@color/white"
       android:visibility="@{model.someVariable == true ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">

   </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Your Activity class would look like

```
public class YourActivityName extends BaseActivity
{
    private ViewModelName viewModelVariable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ViewModelName viewModelVariable = new ViewModelName(); 
        ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.layout_name);
        viewDataBinding.setVariable(BR.model, viewModelVariable);

    }
}
```

ViewModel class would look like

```
public class ViewModelName extends BaseObservable{
    //Logic and variables for view model
    public boolean someVariable;
}
```

Comment: This does not relate to the users  question. He specifically mentioned the ViewModel class. If you're already extending the BaseObservable class, you can't use ViewModel anymore.